# Angular HTTP binding with strictPropertyInitialization=true and HTTP request in service?

Tags: angular, data-binding

I fear this was answered many times before, but I can't find a satisfying solution.

**How do I handle HTTP bindings when I have a service which encapsulates the HTTP request and with `"strictPropertyInitialization": false`?**

Here comes my solution.

The profile-resolver:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ProfileResolverService implements Resolve<Profile> {
  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this.profileService.fetchData();
  }
}
```

which calls the profile-service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ProfileService {
  profileChanged = new EventEmitter<Profile>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private profile: Profile = { username: "", email: "" };

  static createHttpParams(): HttpParams {
    return new HttpParams();
  }

  static createHttpHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
    return new HttpHeaders();
  }

  public fetchData(): Observable<Profile> {
    return this.http.get<Profile>("/api/profile").pipe(
      map((profile) => profile),
      tap((data) => {
        this.profile = data;
        this.profileChanged.emit(this.profile);
      }),
    );
  }

  public getProfile(): Profile {
    return this.profile;
  }

  [...]
}
```

The component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-profile",
  templateUrl: "./profile.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./profile.component.scss"],
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  profile: Profile;

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) {
    // initialize the profile variable
    this.profile = { username: "", email: "" };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // in case the HTTP request has already returned
    this.copyProfile(this.profileService.getProfile());
    // in case the HTTP request has not yet returned
    this.profileService.profileChanged.subscribe((profile) => {
      this.copyProfile(profile);
    });
  }

  // copy the profile attributes but do not set another instance (which breaks the binding)
  private copyProfile(profile: Profile) {
    this.profile.email = profile.email;
    this.profile.username = profile.username;
  }

  [...]
}
```

and stuff like this in the template

```
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="profile.email" name="email">
```

This solution does not fee very comfortable. I avoid errors like *error TS2564: Property 'profile' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.*

or *error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'* or *ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined*

but it is very costly to convert the objects like this. Especially if the objects are more complex.

How is the right way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to cache the profile data?

Comment: No. I just want the service to encapsulate all profile-related HTTP requests and provide the fetched data everywhere needed on one route. (Pop-ups, etc)